# How to launch a batch file from within an HTA

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, cmd, hta

I have a basic HTA in which I am trying to launch a batch file via a button, however when I try to launch the batch file, it does not run.
When I press the button, a command prompt window launches but does not run the script.

Here is as simple example of the code:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Fix</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <FORM>
      <INPUT TYPE="Run" NAME="Button" VALUE="Click">

      <SCRIPT FOR="Button" EVENT="onClick" LANGUAGE="VBScript">
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "cmd.exe '.\example.bat'"
      </SCRIPT>

    </FORM>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

How can I launch a batch file from the same working directory (or sub-directory) as my HTA?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried just calling the batch file by itself instead of calling cmd.exe first?

Comment: Thanks Matt, this worked for me as well as the other suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use **/C** or **/K** parameter as first argument when launching **CMD** process anywhere.

```
 /C     Run Command and then terminate

 /K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
```

Try:

```
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe '/C example.bat'"
```

But that is only the explanation about why your script does not work because don't need to use CMD, you can run directly the batch file 'cause **ShellExecute**.

Comment: Hi, I tried it with the /C switch but it just launched a black cmd box briefly and closes, but doesn't execute the script.

I was able to get it working with Matt's suggestion to just call the .bat file directly, as in:

    WshShell.Run "example.bat"


Thanks for your help!

Comment: UPDATE: My Apologies, that does indeed work as well! I was trying to run it via a UNC path before.

Thanks for this!

Comment: np Bajan but if my answer resolved your problem then please use the Accept button to accept my answer. regards.

Comment: In my case this doesn't work unless I leave an space between `.bat` and the `'"`.