# Run CMD command from hta batch file?

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file, cmd, hta

I have an hta script (batch file), which shows me several buttons and when I click these I want a command to be executed in my cmd. For example, when I press the "IP address" button, the command "ipconfig" should be entered in the cmd and executed. What can I do? Or is that even possible or are there other options for executing a command via this hta script?

Kind regards,
jcjms

Here is my code:

```
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off
setlocal

echo Select an option:
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0"') do set "HTAreply=%%a"
echo End of HTA window, reply: "%HTAreply%"
goto :EOF
-->


<HTML>
<HEAD>
<HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="no" SYSMENU="no" >
<body bgcolor="black">
<TITLE>HTA Buttons</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
window.resizeTo(374,400);


function sleepFor( sleepDuration ){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration){ /* do nothing */ } 
}

function callShellApplication(command){
    var args=document.getElementById('args').value;
    var r = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var res=r.Exec(command +" "+args);    
    var out="";
    while (res.Status == 0)
    {
         sleepFor(100);
    }
    while (!res.StdOut.AtEndOfStream){
        out=out+"\r\n"+res.StdOut.ReadLine();
    }

    var StS=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
    StS.Write(out);     
    //new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(res.StdOut.ReadLine());   
    window.close();
}

function closeHTA(reply){
   var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   fso.GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(reply);
   window.close();
}


</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
   Aruments:<textarea name="args" style="display:none; cols="40" rows="1"></textarea>
   <h1 style="color:white;font-size:40px;">Commands</h1>   
   <hr>
   <button style="background-color:black; border-color:white; color:white" onclick='[what to do here? I want to shutdown other PCs in my local network over the window that opens in cmd (shutdown /iCODELOCK)]'>PC shutdown</button>
   <button style="background-color:black; border-color:white; color:white" onclick='[what to do here? I want to get the PCs IP in cmd (ipconfig)]'>IP-Adress</button>
   <button style="background-color:black; border-color:white; color:white" onclick="closeHTA(1);">close</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16201666/13603288) answer, I think it applies to your case.

Comment: Sounds good, but I can't have all the Batch files on one PC/Directory (dont ask why XD). So I have to execute the command directly from the hta script.

Comment: You can’t have a `body` element inside your `head` that is not a valid structure for a HTML and by extension HTA document.

Comment: I would advise you to read this thread on [dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6581)

Comment: yeah, maybe you are right, sorry I am a total noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you need:

```
onclick="callShellApplication('ipconfig')"
```

A working example might look something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="yes" SYSMENU="no" />
    <title>HTA Buttons</title>
    <script language="JScript">
    //window.resizeTo(374,400);

    function callShellApplication(command){
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"),
        exec = shell.Exec(command);
        output.innerHTML = exec.StdOut.ReadAll().replace(/\r\n/g, '<br>');
    }
    </script>
    <style>
        *{color:white}
        button{background-color:black; border-color:white}
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
    <h1 style="font-size:40px;">Commands</h1>   
    <hr>
    <button onclick="callShellApplication('shutdown /s')">PC shutdown</button>
    <button onclick="callShellApplication('ipconfig')">IP-Adress</button>
    <button onclick="window.close()">close</button>
    <hr>
    <pre id="output"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know, how I could run 2 commands from 1 button click in the same cmd window? Because in my CMD there is something like a CMD "lock", it places befrore the first command a cryptic sign, so if I execute two commands in the same CMD window it only runs the second. So I want to do execute 2. How can I do that? Kind regards, jcjms.

Comment: @jcjms This one should work: `onclick="callShellApplication('cmd /C &quot;ipconfig && TASKLIST&quot;')"`