# Multiple commands on button click callShellApplication?

Tags: javascript, html, cmd, jscript, hta

in my JScript HTA script I have a button that executes a CMD command when I press it: `<button onclick="callShellApplication('ipconfig')">Your IP-Adress</button>` But this is only one command and I want to execute several. For example @echo hello + ipconfig, I need this because the system on which I execute the command has a CMD block, with the first command it always puts a cryptic character in front of it only with the second command is the command executed. So to get around that I want to execute two commands. How do I do that?

Best regards,
jcjms

Comment: I dont know how to iplement your script in mine. And I dont know myself, but if I run 2 commands over a batch it works, but the first command gets "deactivated" by the cryptic sign.

Comment: No no, the admin let a sing appear there, I cant change it. Thats because I want to run2 commands, because he only does secure the first one with this sign. And yes I understand the commands, I am not that dumb : ).  I usually execute ipconfig /all

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/70137040/692942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be critiqued for a one line answer rather than adding a full related code block but this is a minor mod from someone else's answer at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70138712/10802527

```
    <button onclick="callShellApplication('cmd /d /c echo/ &ipconfig')">IP-Adress</button>
```

It is not perfect as it throws the black console widow up for a second before feedback is captured.

My excuse for the simplistic answer is it does exactly what was requested i.e. inject an echo before calling ipconfig.

It seems there may be some Admin autorun trap in cmd chain and using /D should help avoid that if also necessary.

If the echo is needed to acknowledge an autorun message, then it will not be needed if /d stops it acting thus that line may then simplified to:-

```
    <button onclick="callShellApplication('cmd /d /r ipconfig /all')">IP-Adress</button>
```

Comment: I'm doing the whole thing on another PC right now, but it seems to work, should it not work when I'm on the right PC, I just write again. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Don't tried yours yet but this works 100% `<button onclick="callShellApplication('cmd /C &quot;[command 1] && [command 2]&quot;')">Button</button>`